# how to input date as function parameters for solidity in javascript

Tags: date, solidity, smartcontracts

if i have a function like so:

```
function setDeadline(uint256 deadline) public returns(uint256){
  return deadline;
}
```

how do I call it from the migration file?

```
contractName.setDeadline(
  //deadline uint256
);
```

my question is how to input a date in javascript. It will be of the type today+7days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uint256 deadline` is most likely (not sure without context) a unix timestamp.

You can format the JS `Date` object as timestamp using the `getTime()` method. It returns the timestamp in milliseconds, so you'll need to divide it by 1000 to get the timestamp in seconds.

```
let dateInAWeek = new Date(); // now
dateInAWeek.setDate(dateInAWeek.getDate() + 7); // add 7 days
const deadline = Math.floor(dateInAWeek.getTime() / 1000); // unix timestamp

contractName.setDeadline(deadline);
```